# Macbook 3 Bleeps on Startup

Tags: macbook-pro

I am having a strange issue with my 2010 MBP. I recently upgraded the memory to 8GB ram and it was working fine, but now when I load it up I get 3 bleeps.

I opened it up and checked the ram was in correctly. I powered back up and it worked fine. I closed the lid, left it for the night, came back to it and booted her up and it done it again. I turned it off, and back on, and it booted up.

It goes through stages like this when I have to keep trying to power it on before it will eventually come on.

I've heard it's a RAM issue, but if so why am I still able to boot up the MacBook after a couple of attempts?

I'm not sure how to solve this bootup issue. Once it's booted it works fine and I have no issues UNLESS I close the lid, and it then has to be restarted.

I can't understand how it worked fine before.

Is there anything I can try to fix this apart from replacing the RAM (I can't afford new RAM).

Comment: You didn't mention if the RAM available to OS X matches the physical RAM installed once it reboots.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed and issue with the RAM, and, despite the fact that you've already *rechecked* the placing of it, **three** beeps means that there's something wrong with how the RAM is placed in their banks.

**Swapping** the RAM modules usually does the trick.

You could, too, reboot just with one module to see what happens, and, afterwards, place the other.